# Laravel deployment to the App engine broken after a composer command

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, composer-php, google-cloud-build

I am programming a PHP API using Laravel 7. My dev process is like that:

Local (Homestead@Virtualbox: Ubuntu) => Github => Google Cloud build (deployment triggered by a master commit) => Google App Engine <> Google Cloud SQL

For now I had no problem deploying my app this way but yesterday I tried to add a composer package (mpociot/laravel-apidoc-generator). After some local tests where everything worked just fine I committed my master branch and my GC Build trigger tried to deploy the app on my App engine instance.

The process terminated with a error I have never seen so far. I then reverted my latest commit, going back to the state where I never ran the composer command and committed my master branch again: the deployment succeeded as usual.

So as there was something happening with the composer command, I investigated further.

Here is the log I get in my GC Build failed deployment:

```
FETCHSOURCE
Fetching storage object: gs://701891080190.cloudbuild-source.googleusercontent.com/7541db97159423ca9ec0996eb740a404aef3c4b9-ec3f59e5-8eb5-46f9-98ab-6848be6dd6f8.tar.gz#1589712757789375
Copying gs://701891080190.cloudbuild-source.googleusercontent.com/7541db97159423ca9ec0996eb740a404aef3c4b9-ec3f59e5-8eb5-46f9-98ab-6848be6dd6f8.tar.gz#1589712757789375...
/ [0 files][    0.0 B/  9.4 MiB]                                                
/ [1 files][  9.4 MiB/  9.4 MiB]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/9.4 MiB.                                      
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Services to deploy:

descriptor:      [/workspace/app.yaml]
source:          [/workspace]
target project:  [#####]
target service:  [#####]
target version:  [20200517t105250]
target url:      [https://#####.ew.r.appspot.com]


Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  
Beginning deployment of service [heavnt-test]...
#============================================================#
#= Uploading 2 files to Google Cloud Storage                =#
#============================================================#
File upload done.
Updating service [heavnt-test]...
.............................................................................................................................................................................................................failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 0dd458db-cd18-463a-b0de-034668d9802a status: FAILURE.
Build error details: {"error":{"errorType":"BuildError","canonicalCode":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","errorId":"39857F2F","errorMessage":"INFO     FTL version php-v0.17.0\nINFO     Beginning FTL build for php\nINFO     FTL arg passed: exposed_ports None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache_repository eu.gcr.io/hotpot-63d32/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d\nINFO     FTL arg passed: tar_base_image_path None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: export_cache_stats False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: builder_output_path \"\"\nINFO     FTL arg passed: name eu.gcr.io/hotpot-63d32/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:a30cd452-e54a-46f4-a041-9b975258909a\nINFO     FTL arg passed: ttl 168\nINFO     FTL arg passed: global_cache False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache True\nINFO     FTL arg passed: upload True\nINFO     FTL arg passed: sh_c_prefix False\nINFO     FTL arg passed: fail_on_error True\nINFO     FTL arg passed: base eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/php72:php72_20200412_7_2_29_RC00\nINFO     FTL arg passed: output_path None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache_key_version v0.17.0\nINFO     FTL arg passed: cache_salt \nINFO     FTL arg passed: directory /workspace\nINFO     FTL arg passed: entrypoint None\nINFO     FTL arg passed: additional_directory /.googleconfig\nINFO     FTL arg passed: destination_path /srv\nINFO     FTL arg passed: verbosity NOTSET\nINFO     starting: full build\nINFO     starting: builder initialization\nINFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/php72:php72_20200412_7_2_29_RC00'\nINFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'eu.gcr.io/hotpot-63d32/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:a30cd452-e54a-46f4-a041-9b975258909a'\nINFO     builder initialization took 0 seconds\nINFO     starting: build process for FTL image\nINFO     starting: rm_vendor_dir\nINFO     rm_vendor_dir rm -rf /workspace/vendor\nINFO     `rm_vendor_dir` stdout:\n\nINFO     rm_vendor_dir took 0 seconds\nINFO     descriptor_contents:\n{\n    \"_readme\": [\n        \"This file locks the dependencies of your project to a known state\",\n        \"Read more about it at https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies\",\n        \"This file is @generated automatically\"\n    ],\n    \"content-hash\": \"f8027c7d3e5d36c84e1215645bb96efa\",\n    \"packages\": [\n        {\n            \"name\": \"asm89/stack-cors\",\n            \"version\": \"1.3.0\",\n            \"source\": {\n                \"type\": \"git\",\n                \"url\": \"https://github.com/asm89/stack-cors.git\",\n                \"reference\": \"b9c31def6a83f84b4d4a40d35996d375755f0e08\"\n            },\n            \"dist\": {\n                \"type\": \"zip\",\n                \"url\": \"https://api.github.com/repos/asm89/stack-cors/zipball/b9c31def6a83f84b4d4a40d35996d375755f0e08\",\n                \"reference\": \"b9c31def6a83f84b4d4a40d35996d375755f0e08\",\n                \"shasum\": \"\"\n            },\n            \"require\": {\n                \"php\": \"\u003e=5.5.9\",\n                \"symfony/http-foundation\": \"~2.7|~3.0|~4.0|~5.0\",\n                \"symfony/http-kernel\": \"~2.7|~3.0|~4.0|~5.0\"\n            },\n            \"require-dev\": {\n                \"phpunit/phpunit\": \"^5.0 || ^4.8.10\",\n                \"squizlabs/php_codesniffer\": \"^2.3\"\n            },\n            \"type\": \"library\",\n            \"extra\": {\n                \"branch-alias\": {\n                    \"dev-master\": \"1.2-dev\"\n                }\n            },\n            \"autoload\": {\n                \"psr-4\": {\n                    \"Asm89\\\\Stack\\\\\": \"src/Asm89/Stack/\"\n                }\n            },\n            \"notification-url\": \"https://packagist.org/downloads/\",\n            \"license\": [\n                \"MIT\"\n            ],\n            \"authors\": [\n                {\n                    \"name\": \"Alexander\",\n                    \"email\": \"iam.asm89@gmail.com\"\n                }\n            ],\n            \"description\": \"Cross-origin resource sharing library and stack middleware\",\n            \"homepage\": \"https://github.com/asm8.
Check the build log for errors: ####SEE BELOW####
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Le full content of the log is too big (16k+ lines) for this site but it ends like this:

```
Step #1 - "builder": Generating optimized autoload files
Step #1 - "builder": > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
Step #1 - "builder": > @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Step #1 - "builder": Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": error: `composer_install` returned code: 1
Step #1 - "builder": Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
Step #1 - "builder":     "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
Step #1 - "builder":     exec code in run_globals
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 65, in <module>
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 57, in main
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/ftl_error.py", line 58, in UserErrorHandler
Step #1 - "builder": IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '""/output'
Finished Step #1 - "builder"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/gae-runtimes/php72_app_builder:php72_20200412_7_2_29_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

My App.yaml file:

```
service: heavnt-test
runtime: php72

env_variables:
    ## Put production environment variables here.
    APP_KEY: base64:TRoTxS+x5PeiAOlwV/F1AwyfgV6y8mZloqGastMYylQ=
    APP_STORAGE: /tmp
    VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
    SESSION_DRIVER: cookie  
    APP_SERVICES_CACHE: /tmp/services.php
    APP_PACKAGES_CACHE: /tmp/packages.php
    APP_CONFIG_CACHE: /tmp/config.php
    APP_ROUTES_CACHE: /tmp/routes.php

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js))$
  static_files: public/\1
  upload: public/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js)$

- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto

entrypoint: serve /public/index.php
```

My Cloudbuild.yaml file:

```
steps:
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ["app", "deploy"]
timeout: "1600s"
```

I tried to check, using Github Desktop, the changes happening on my files when adding my composer package but there are so many files added and changed that I had no clue

EDIT 18/05/2020:

In the 16k+ lines log, I found this issue:

```
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     composer_install composer install --no-dev --no-progress --no-suggest --no-interaction
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `composer_install` stdout:
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": In PackageManifest.php line 177:
Step #1 - "builder":                                                                           
Step #1 - "builder":   The /workspace/bootstrap/cache directory must be present and writable.
```

I am not sure how to figure out if this is the problem I am experiencing as everything works fine in local and used to work fine online.

Comment: Please share more details. Usually, Composer would not throw any Python errors

Comment: I edited my post to show the "bootstrap/cache" problem I found in the log but as everything is fine in local and used to work live before, I can't figure if this is the issue nor how to fix it (chmod a folder while deploying).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To investigate further I tried to deploy my app directly from my local setup (cloud app deploy), so without using my Github>GCloud Build bridge.

It deployed like a charm so I tried accessing the docs package I initially wanted to add and as the static files in public/docs/ weren't served I added those lines to my app.yaml:

```
- url: /docs
  static_dir: public/docs
```

**So, as far as I'm aware, this is the only lines I changed.**

To try, I committed this code (docs package+app.yaml lines) via my original process and it deployed perfectly (triggered multiple times to be sure).

So to conclude, I have absolutely no idea how and why this happened and I truly hope it doesn't appear again.

Comment: To add to this story. This issue happen again from time to time so, I'll do a ```gcloud app deploy``` from my local terminal, deploy with success and then my GC Build trigger start working again. I will not bother contacting Google support with public launch anyway. Will add up here then.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having issues today (2023, Laravel 9/10), the problem is the `php artisan package:discover` command in the composer.json `post-autoload-dump` script, which checks if the `bootstrap/cache` directory is present and writable. If it isn't, it quits with errorlevel 1, breaking the GAE build.

To solve this, edit your composer.json scripts like this:

```json
...
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "mkdir -p ./bootstrap/cache/",
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "chmod -R 755 bootstrap\/cache",
            "php artisan cache:clear"
        ],
...
```

Source: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/issues/1167#issuecomment-747304053